# Rad Editor style Issue

Tags: html, css, telerik, radeditor

Hi i am new to Rad Editor,

i have set background for Rad Editor it looks like

```
   <div style="background-color: #ffff00;">
```

but when i use same code in my another machine

```
   <div style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);">
```

both of the system configuration are same

browser also same

I think it may thier is setting in the Rad Editor

i dont why it changes please give me some solution to solve this

Thanks in Advance

Comment: why not use any other available editor and then editor can not generate or overwrite styles

Comment: any complex WYSIWYG editor that offers a good feature set is bound to change the content a bit, especially in complex cases and commands. 

@opener - as Rumen said, see how your setup differs from an example provided by the vendor to see how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not reproducible in the live demos of RadEditor under IE11, Chrome and Firefox: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/builtincontentfilters/defaultcs.aspx

Check whether you have not disabled any of the built-in content filters of the control.